Fixing 401 Unauthorized Error with Socialite Discord
I'm performing code checks to see if the current user is a member of the guild or not using the following code (using the Socialite library - discord):
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('discord')
        ->with(['access_type' => 'offline'])
        ->scopes([
            'identify',
            'email',
            'guilds',
            'applications.commands',
            'applications.commands.permissions.update',
            'guilds.join',
            'bot',
            'connections',
            'guilds.members.read',
            'role_connections.write',
        ])
        ->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('discord')->user();
    $discordId = $user->getId();
    $accessToken = $user->token;
    $refreshToken = $user->refreshToken;
    $guildId = '1220351452170555402';
    $isMember = $this->checkGuildMember($discordId, $accessToken, $guildId);
    dd($isMember);
    if ($isMember) {
        dd('mem');
    } else {
        dd('notmem');
    }
}

protected function checkGuildMember($discordId, $accessToken, $guildId)
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    try {
        $response = $client->get("https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{$guildId}/members/{$discordId}", [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            ],
        ]);

        return $response->getStatusCode() == 200;
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
        if ($e->hasResponse()) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            \Log::error('Discord API Error:', [
                'status_code' => $statusCode,
                'response_body' => json_decode($body, true),
            ]);
            dd([
                'status_code' => $statusCode,
                'response_body' => json_decode($body, true),
            ]);
        }

        return false;
    }
}


I tried dd($user->approvedScopes) and it returned an array:
array:8 [▼
  0 => "guilds.join"
  1 => "guilds"
  2 => "guilds.members.read"
  3 => "identify"
  4 => "connections"
  5 => "applications.commands.permissions.update"
  6 => "email"
  7 => "role_connections.write"
]


But when running the checkGuildMember() function, it returned an array:
array:2 [▼
  "status_code" => 401
  "response_body" => array:2 [▼
    "message" => "401: Unauthorized"
    "code" => 0
  ]
]


Fixing 401 Unauthorized Error with Socialite Discord
